# Mma10 mystery: Failure of pure function substitution with Interpretation?

Tags: bugs, pattern-matching, replacement, pure-function

**Bug introduced in 10.0.0 and fixed in 10.0.1**

---

I had code to display with subscripts from [Displaying index as subscript on output: e.g. C[i] -> C_i with Notation[...] or Interpretation[..]?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30884/) which is now breaking an innocuous pure function substitution as in [Looking for an elegant way to solve a (system of) ODEs/functional equations with undetermined coefficients](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/51103)   The substitution itself has nothing to do with any actual display of subscripts.

I am having a little trouble creating a minimal example, but here goes.  First, in Mma10 try the pre-side effect code:

```
ODE = F'[z] == g F[z]
Fguess = {F-> (Exp[a #]&)}
ODE /. Fguess //FullSimplify

=> e^(a z)(a - g)== 0, the proper output
```

Now, add in the following code, stripped down from that previous example.  This isn't intended to actually have anything to do with the substitution, but is causing side effects.

```
NotScriptedVarQ[z_] := ! MemberQ[$scriptedfunctionsvars, z, Infinity];
makeDef[pat_, body_] := (MakeBoxes[a : pat, fmt_] := 
ToBoxes[Interpretation[body, a], fmt] /; 
 MemberQ[Union[$scriptedconstants, $scriptedfunctions], 
  Unevaluated@h];
  )
makeDef[h_Symbol[argssub__?NotScriptedVarQ], h[argssub]];
$scriptedconstants = {};
$scriptedfunctions = {};
$scriptedfunctionsvars = {};
```

Now, try the substitution and a few permutations:

```
(*The ODE and guess are*)
ODE = F'[z] == g F[z]
Fguess = {F -> (Exp[a #] &)}
(*Substituting NOW DOESN'T work*)
ODE /. Fguess // FullSimplify
(*But if the guess is NOT displayed before the substitution(i.e., no ;) WORKS!*)
Fguess = {F -> (Exp[a #] &)};
ODE /. Fguess // FullSimplify
(*And if the guess is substituted directly, IT WORKS!*)
F'[z] == g F[z] /. {F -> (Exp[a #] &)} // FullSimplify
```

As this used to work fine in Mma9, I imagine this is a bug.  If so, any idea of a workaround?

One last thing I learned:  If you change the definition so that `NotScriptedVarQ[z_] :=  True`, or change it to always be False, the bug is no longer there!

Comment: What are the `Print` expressions suppose to accomplish? Are they supposed to function as comments? Should that be the case, then use _Mathematica_'s comment syntax, e.g., `(* a comment *)`.

Comment: Sorry, you are right, I just had them in there to keep track of the output. They don't effect the bug

Comment: Prints converted to comments.  Thanks.

Comment: It seems this bug has been fixed in 10.0.1; I added a header accordingly.  If you find this to not be true please remove that header (and let me know).

Comment: Confirmed, fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't yet explain the behavior but I can greatly reduce your minimum example:

```
MakeBoxes[a_ /; FreeQ["foo", a], fmt_] := "bar" /; False

ODE = F'[z] == g F[z];
Fguess = {F -> (Exp[a #] &)}

ODE /. {F -> (Exp[a #] &)}
ODE /. Fguess
```

> ```
> {F -> (Exp[a #1] &)}
>
> a E^(a z) == E^(a z) g
>
> Derivative[1][F][z] == g F[z]
> ```

***Critically:***

- If I suppress the output of `Fguess = {F -> (Exp[a #] &)}` by appending a `;` the problem exhibited in the final line of code goes away.
- If I replace `FreeQ["foo", a]` with `FreeQ["foo", HoldPattern @ a]` the problem goes away.
  (Kernel restart required.)

Apparently the evaluation of `a` within `FreeQ` (or `MemberQ`) when `MakeBoxes` is performed on the output of the line `Fguess = {F -> (Exp[a #] &)}` breaks something but at this point I have no idea what.

Comment: That did it!  Changing to `MemberQ[$scriptedfunctionsvars, HoldPattern@ z, Infinity]` seems to have fixed everything.  This sure looks like a bug to me, how does Wolfram like these things to be submitted?

Comment: @jlperla Under the **Help** menu there should be a **Give Feedback** item you can use for that.  I'm glad this solves your problem.  I too believe it is a bug as I can't think of any other explanation for the behavior.  I'll add that tag to the question.  If later I am proven wrong so be it.

Comment: @jlperla Oh, and thanks for the Bounty!

Comment: Sent to them.  Thank you so much for looking at this and finding a workaround.

Comment: @jlperla By the way is there a reason you are using `! MemberQ[$scriptedfunctionsvars, HoldPattern @ z, Infinity];` rather than `FreeQ[$scriptedfunctionsvars, HoldPattern @ z]`?

Comment: For whatever reason, it didn't pass my test cases (which was my stopping criteria on the code).  I couldn't figure out why.

Comment: @jlperla If you're able to give me an example I think I'll learn something.  Please, if you have time.

Comment: Take a look at http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30884/displaying-index-as-subscript-on-output-e-g-ci-c-i-with-notation-or  (which was originally based on the code you gave me).  I wrote down the final code I used as an answer at the bottom.  (the only thing I added was a `OverDot`case) There is also a complete listing of the test cases in that post.

Comment: If you wish to refactor this, especially if it is as a module `DisplayScripted` or something like that, I am sure it would be appreciated by all.